# How to back up files without live disk?

Tags: backup, data-recovery

I recently upgraded to 13.10. The installation seemed to run fine, after the system rebooted I got the error "The system is running in low-graphics mode” After a few hours of googling no solution I found fixed this problem.

I tried to downgrade using a disk and got the same error after installation. I then tried to back up my files using the disk by selecting "try ubuntu".

I really need to recover my data, I have weeks worth of work on there and some bitcoin I cannot afford to lose.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand why backing up does not work? Does the live disk not run? In low graphics, you can't reach your files?

Comment: The live disk now gives me the same error "The system is running in low-graphics mode" I cannot proceed from there.

Comment: Aha, I see. ALthough the backup thing is the "derived"problem, it looks like the real problem is that your graphics driver is not loading correctly. Here you will find an impressive number of solutions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error If your solution cannot be found, let it know.

Comment: I tried everything on there last night. Still nothing, thanks though. I just cant understand why separate installs are giving me the same error.

Comment: in low graphics mode, can you use the shell?

Comment: I can get to the terminal by hitting crtl + alt + F1

Comment: well, you may try using the terminal client if you can get in to it. Where you need to save those DATA(s). BTW, I will also suggest to refer the link that @Jacob mentioned as this is something to do with graphics driver.

Comment: I've tried nearly everything in that link. I'm trying to use linux mint to get to my files at the moment and getting a similar error. I still cant understand why separate installs are giving me the same error. If I bit the bullet and wiped my drive would a clean install at least get my OS back?

Comment: òk, I will answer in a minute..

Comment: I just updated my answer, I oversaw the fact that in my GUI liv disc I already mounted the partition with the data, something you will have to do manually, from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot get any advanced graphics running, but you still can log in and use the terminal of your installed Ubuntu, do the following to save your data:

**method 1**

- start the computer, connect an external drive to store the backup

First you have to find out the exact drivename and mountpoint of the external drive:

- start a terminal and type `lsblk`

You will see a list of drives and their partitions; your external drive will be listed as well and you will have its exact name and mountpoint(it will probably be mounted in `/media`).

- type in the terminal:
  cp -r `/home/yourname /mountpoint/drivename` to copy your data to the external drive.

**method 2** (yet) using the live usb or cd

- Connect an external drive to store the backup
- Boot from a live cd or the live usb
- Find out what the mountpoint is of the external drive like in method 1 (`lsblk`)

The harddrive of your computer and its partitions will be listed as well, but will not be mounted.

- Make an educated guess on which partition your data is stored
  (you will probably recognize it by its size).
- Mount the partition by the command `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` (sda1 = for example)
  check if you mounted the right partition; cd to `/mnt` and type `ls` to see if your datafolder (I assume your username) is listed.
  if not, mount another partition and repeat the procedure.

Then you have all information to do the backup:

- type after the prompt:
  cp -r /mnt/home/your_username/mountpoint/drivename`
  )
  And your home directory will be copied to the external drive.

Comment: No need to explain that the paths `/home/yourname` (in the cp -r command of method 1) and `/mnt/home/your_username` (in the cp -r command of method 2) are examples, and depend on where your data is stored.